# Suggested flow-control structure for order-dependant operations

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dry

I've run into the following issue which is not difficult to solve by any stretch of the imagination but **I would like to know what the best / most elegant solution is.**

I have the following method that the prototype of looks like this:

```
bool Team::isEveryoneDead(int teamOnTurn);
```

There are **two teams** available and depending on what instance of the team is currently on turn, I would like to check whether every Character in the team is dead **in this very particular order**:

1. Loop trough all the Characters in the team that's **not** on turn **first**. Should there be any character that's alive, **stop** looping (and goto step 2.). Should there be **noone** alive, **terminate** the function and return.
2. Now that I know  that the team that's **not** on turn contains at least one character that's alive, loop trough the team that's currently on turn and check for the same thing. Should I find **someone** alive, **stop looping** and terminate / return.

The argument `int teamOnTurn` allows me to resolve the instance of Team that's currently on turn. **The order in which i evaluate the "alive condition" is of great importance here.**

Now, there are several approaches that can be taken, say hardcoding the order (since there are only 2 possible orders) and resolving the order by checking who's on turn and then executing the branch that already has the specific order like this:

```
bool Team::isEveryoneDead(int teamOnTurn) {
    if (Team::Blue == teamOnTurn) {
        checkThis();
        checkThat();
    } else {
        checkThat();
        checkThis();
    }
}
```

This solution however wouldn't quite work for say 5! permutations for specific call-ordering for more items. **What technique should one deploy to solve this with the utmost elegance :**) ?

Thanks in advance, Scarlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating another internal method that actually does the checking, and let the isEveryoneDead() method orchestrate the order in which the teams are checked, maybe something like this:

```
bool Team::isEveryoneDead(int teamOnTurn) {
    bool isFound = isEveryoneDeadInternal( /* params for team not on turn */ );
    if(isFound) {
        isFound = isEveryoneDeadInternal( /* params for team on turn */ );
    }
    return isFound;
} 

// This method know nothing about on turn or off turn
bool Team:isEveryoneDeadInternal() {
    // Loop through all characters in the team, checking if any are alive
    // When the first live character is found, return true
    // else return false
}
```

This is a concept called DRY : Dont Repeat Yourself

Comment: That's pretty much what the hardcoding does isn't it ? How would you resolve the ordering in the internal function ?

Comment: @Scarlet, I updated the code to be a bit more clear. The idea is to not repeat the code in `isEveryoneDeadInternal()` and make it agnostic to on/off turn

Comment: Oh, yeah, i see your point, that's what i actually meant. I was mostly wondering whether i shouldn't do some parameter based function pointer assignments and all that but i guess that would be an overkill. Thanks, accepting.